# My bitcoin is in a platform where their website is down

Tags: wallet, server, websites

I have a question and looking for advice on what to do.  My bitcoin is stored in an account called Aptimarket.  The website for this company is in a redemption list.  Their domain is now under Namecheap.  I contacted Namecheap and was informed that Aptimarket is in a redemption list and might be deleted soon.  My bitcoins are in an account with Aptimarket and not able to get to my account.  I am concerned about this as where are the he bitcoins?   I’m sure I’m not the only customer who has an account with Aptimarket.  I can’t get into my account because of Aptimarkets website not active.  Any help on this or any information would be appreciated. Thank you.  Rose

Comment: While not personally familiar with this site, it's marked on multiple scam tracking sites as fraudulent. That means that more than likely you fell victim to a cryptocurrency scam, and your funds may be forever lost. You probably should consult above link and local law enforcement to see if there any legal measures you can take.

Comment: What are the scam tracking sites you checked this company on?